# How to get http request origin in php

Tags: php, apache, http, post, get

I want to create an API, and to authenticate API consumers, I will provide an API KEY, App-id and App-Secret. The problem is that I want to know where the http Request is coming from, so that I can know if the Host that is making que request is the registered Host. For example : www.someone.com has an app-id :0001, app-secret:1200 and api-key:458. If this credentials are used to make A request, I want to know if the requester is really www.someone.com

Comment: For origin use this `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] . "");` and then check credentials from GET or POST variable

Comment: Using the origin as a security measure is beyond useless. This header can easily [be faked](https://requestable.pieterhordijk.com/imCuvc). Instead you might want to work with a callback to pass some "request token" (think about how the oauth flow works).

Comment: Using HTTP_ORIGIN or HTTP_REFERER without checking them is "in essence" the same as doing "*" which can open up subtle security holes so is discouraged, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001269/what-are-the-security-risks-of-setting-access-control-allow-origin

Comment: An answer to the actual question **"How to get http request origin"** can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41326257/how-i-can-get-origin-of-request-with-php#answer-41335048

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. It is the address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify `HTTP_REFERER` as a feature.

For further restrictions you can perform the following. `example.com` should be changed to your domain.

**IIS set below in web config**:

```
add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://www.example.com"
```

**Apache set below in httpd.conf/apache.conf**

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://www.example.com"
```

Comment: The referrer and the origin are two different things.

Comment: Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

Comment: A better answer to that question can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41326257/how-i-can-get-origin-of-request-with-php#answer-41335048

Comment: As @DanFromGermany touched on, ORIGIN and REFERER are two different things - `HTTP_ORIGIN` is the better in this case than `HTTP_REFERER`; if `HTTP_ORIGIN` is missing then you may wish to fall back to using `HTTP_REFERER`, but I would advise against this for security (it's easier to change the referer than the origin, as origin is listed as a "forbidden" header and browsers *should* prevent any changes to origin from taking place).

Answer (score 26):

Generally, this header should do the job. Having the domain name in this header

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] . "");
// use domain name instead of $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] above
```

but if you want to check for more info, use something like the following snippet

```
$allowed = array('domain1', 'domain2', 'domain3'); 

if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']) && in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'], $allowed)){
    // SELECT credentials for this user account from database
    if(isset($_GET['api_key'], $_GET['app_secret'])
        && $_GET['api_key'] == 'api_key_from_db' 
        && $_GET['app_secret'] == 'app_secret_from_db'
    ){
        // all fine
    }else{
        // not allowed
    }
}else{
    // not allowed
}
```

If the users have to pass more data to your service, use `POST` instead of `GET`

Comment: If the $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] variable returns me the Client_IP and not the website address, How am I supposed to autheticate the website??

Comment: @m_junior `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` returns the IP address of the server under which the current script is executing.

Comment: @m_junior The `$allowed` array from above may look even this way `$allowed = array('domain1' => '1.2.3.4', 'domain2' => '5.6.7.8', 'domain3' => '2.4.6.8');` and then you can use `gethostbyname('domain')` and compare returned IP of the host with the IP in your array.

Comment: Does it mean that If an website has a javascript that makes a post to my API, once I receive the request the $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] WILL be filled with the website IP and not the client IP??? sorry for the ignorance level!

Comment: @m_junior No worries, feel free to ask :) If you need the IP of the host (where the website is hosted) use `gethostbyname('www.your-client.com')` but if you need the IP of the computer from where the request came from, use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

Comment: Instead of putting every possible origin in, which is bad by default, you could also use `*`, which is not better. This answer introduces a security problem.

Comment: @DanFromGermany Pointing to something that might seem to you wrong and at the same time not providing any other, maybe a better solution, is by default a very bad, selfish and even childish attitude.

Comment: @DanFromGermany how is having a white-list of permitted origins a bad thing?

Comment: Not all user webservers will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_ORIGIN as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

Comment: @DanFromGermany @LeonanCarvalho : `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header doesn't introduce a security problem. There is no difference in security on the server side if that header is set ot not. This header is only there for adding security on the end-user-side. So no malicous website may use your API and receive user session data (cookies). And this only if the user is using a common browser that listens for this header and hasn't been manipulated (by virus etc). To secure the server side, other measures must be taken.

Comment: Anyway it is better to only set `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] . "");` within the first `if` statement.

Comment: @hex494D49 why do you rejected my edit? Your code has 4 syntax errors and isn't optimal formatted for SO.

Comment: I am not sure anymore what happened when I commented like a year ago. Important is the array `$allowed` and that makes it a good answer.

Comment: @MA-Maddin As a reason for editing, you mentioned "improved formatting" and you didn't mention any syntax errors. I personally don't like spaces after each keyword, so I thought your editing actually isn't an improvement. But since you're right about syntax errors, I left them so you can correct them (again) and I'll accept your edit. Sorry and thanks :)

Comment: @DanFromGermany Just wanted to thank you for your last comment :)

Comment: I have a question. Can't the `HTTP_ORIGIN` value be spoofed/faked?

Answer (score 12):

**Laravel 5**: in request method controller:

```
$origin = request()->headers->get('origin');
```

Comment: to get all headers: `request()->headers->all();`

Comment: Can't an unauthorized person simply change the request headers in his client to send a domain of an authorized domain and this way circumvent the check?

Comment: I just found the answer on a different thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21058346/4688612

Comment: `origin` is not sent with GET

Comment: @mangusta browser  add `origin` header for CORS requests - [more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59353387/860099)  - if you don't send CORS request then browser not add this header and probably php not set it too (or probably set some default value - but I don't check this on php side ).

Answer (score 6):

Technically neither `origin` nor `referer` are required HTTP headers, all of these answers are based on specific browser headers sent, and basing your system on different behaviors of clients is a bad idea.

The correct answer is you can't reliably get the client origin on every request because it isn't required as part of the HTTP specification.

Answer (score 4):

Using a `var_dump` you can see all that the `request` has to offer.

```
var_dump($_REQUEST);
```

Do a `var_dump`  on the `server` global as well. It contains alot of usefull information.

```
var_dump($_SERVER);
```

Comment: I use this one on my front end server and I forgot to remove it and the server got hacked. Very dangerous for a lot 'useful information'

Answer (score 2):

I think what you mean is that you want to access the "Origin" header in the request headers (as opposed to setting it in the response headers).

For this the easiest way is to access the built in **getallheaders()** function - which is an alias for **apache_request_headers**() - N.B. this is assuming you are using php as a module.

This returns an array so the Origin header should be available like this:

```
$request_headers = getallheaders();
$origin = $request_headers['Origin'];
```

If you are using php via something like fastcgi then I believe it would be made available in the environment - usually capitalised and prefixed by "HTTP_"  so it should be `$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']`.

Hope that helps anyone else looking for this :)

Comment: getallheaders(); doen't exist in php-fpm or php-fastcgi

Comment: Yes this is why I mentioned that is was assuming you were using php as a module (mod_php) and that otherwise its available as an environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

in laravel 7 this worked for me

request()->headers->get('referer');

Comment: first check it with request()->headers; then you can add "->get(' ..needed parameter.. ');"