# How I can get origin of request with PHP?

Tags: php, ajax, apache, request, cross-domain

If someone send XHR request from `some-client.com` to `some-rest.com`, I want get origin(**domain name, not client ip**) of the request with PHP.

The possible solutions:

- Maybe I can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']` but I don't know if it is a standard.
- I see another header like `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` or `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`, but some cases this return the real `hostname` and not the real `domain`.
- And `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` gives the client IP.

Whats is the correct way to get origin of request like a domain name with PHP?

Thanks!

Comment: From what I know, `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is your solution, you can only get the IP not the DNS

Answer (score 32, accepted):

According to the article *[HTTP access control (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)* by MDN:

All requests must be set `Origin` header to work correctly under CORS(*Cross-origin resource sharing*) mechanism.

The "**Origin**" request header is part of [RFC 6454](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6454#section-7) and **describes it as part of CORS mechanism** and is compatible with all browsers according  to MDN.

Description by MDN:

> The `Origin` request header indicates where a fetch originates from. It
> doesn't include any path information, but only the server name. It is
> sent with CORS requests, as well as with POST requests. It is similar
> to the Referer header, but, unlike this header, it doesn't disclose
> the whole path.
>
> Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin

**Example by MDN:**
[image]

**So, to get origin of the XHR request with PHP you can use:**

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']
```

**And, in the case of a direct request, *you can combine* `HTTP_REFERER` and `REMOTE_ADDR` like:**

```
if (array_key_exists('HTTP_REFERER', $_SERVER)) {
    $origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
} else {
    $origin = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
```

**So, the possible final solution is:**

```
if (array_key_exists('HTTP_ORIGIN', $_SERVER)) {
    $origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];
}
else if (array_key_exists('HTTP_REFERER', $_SERVER)) {
    $origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
} else {
    $origin = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
```

MDN is [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/).

Thanks a lot for help @trine, @waseem-bashir, @p0lt10n, and others persons.

Answer (score 2):

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']  // HTTP Origin header
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']    // HTTP Host header
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] // HTTP Referer header
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']  // HTTP Client's Public IP
```

Let's discuss above `$_SERVER` parameters.

First, XHR is at client side and it bounds with a http client. As Origin and Referer headers are not mandatory, a client other than standard web browser will not set that. Next Host header may not be mandatory. If your REST server uses virtual hosts, this header is a must to route requests correctly. But this header doesn't have any detail about the client. Only unique thing for http client is Public IP. But this corresponds to many clients as ISP's use network address translations or proxies.

Since everything is relative and within bounds, [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) like mechanisms are built on HTTP Origin header. Clients are assumed and advised to be using standard browsers.

In your case, my opinion is it's OK to depend on Origin header. You can implement [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) mechanism if it suits for you.

Answer (score 1):

in php you can get using $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].
if you are using codeigniter then you can get the referrer using $this->agent->is_referral().

Comment: This is `Referer`` header and some browser don't use this header. Learn more here: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer