# In the respective of security, is it meaningful to allow CORS for specific domains?

Tags: http, cors

We can set and allow cross-origin-resource-sharing for

**All domains** , **Specific domains** and **Not allow for any domains**

But I wonder allowing **CORS** for **specific domains** meaningful.

If a hacker knows the domains that server allows. (e.g `www.facebook.com`)

Hacker can fake the **origin header** in the request as `www.facebook.com`

Thus, in the perspective of security. I think only **Allow all domains** and **Not allow for any domains** are meaningful. Since it is very easy to fake the **origin** of the requester

Am I right??

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058183/whats-to-stop-malicious-code-from-spoofing-the-origin-header-to-exploit-cors/21058346#21058346

Comment: The security perspective of CORS is not the server but the user agent, that's what helps me keeping the concept in mind correctly. None of the options will save you form securing your server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers are where CORS restrictions are enforced. And browsers *know* the real origin a script runs in. That’s how they work. If they didn’t, there would be zero security on the Web.

So browsers do CORS checks against what they know to be the real origin of the JavaScript code that’s making an XHR or `fetch()` request—not against the value of the `Origin` header.

And browsers are what *set* the `Origin` request header and send it over the network to begin with. Browsers set the `Origin` value based on what they know to be the real origin, and not for their own use—because they already know what the origin is and that value is what they use internally.

So even if you manage to change an `Origin` header a browser sends over the network, that won’t matter to the browser—it’s going to ignore that value and continue checking against the real origin.

---

**More details**

As far as CORS goes, servers just send back documents, with an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header and other CORS headers, to any client that requests them.

Consider if you use `curl` or something to request a document from a server: The server doesn’t check the `Origin` header and refuse to send the document if the requesting origin doesn’t match the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. The server sends the response regardless.

And as far as clients go, `curl` and non-browser tools don’t have the concept of an origin to begin with and so don’t usually send any `Origin` header to begin with. You can make `curl` send one—with any value you want—but it’s pointless because servers don’t care what the value is.

And `curl`, etc., don’t check the value of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header the server sends, and refuse to get a document if the request’s `Origin` header doesn’t match the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the server response. They just get the document.

But browsers are different. Browser engines are really the only clients that have the notion of an origin to begin with, and that know the actual origin a Web application’s JavaScript is running in.

And unlike `curl`, etc., browsers will not let your script get a document if the XHR or `fetch()` call requesting  it is from an origin not allowed in the server’s `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

And again, the way browsers determine what the origin is by *already knowing* what the origin is, not based on the value of whatever `Origin` request header might end up getting sent in the request.