# How does EnableCors restrict the origin access

Tags: asp.net, ajax, http, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have created a WebAPI controller as below

```
[EnableCors("http://localhost:1234", "*", "*"]
public class DummyController : ApiController
{
    public string GetDummy()
    {
        return "Iam not DUMMY";
    }
}
```

When I hit the service using ajax from my application which is hosted on `locahost:5678` It throws error since it is not allowed but when I hit the same API from restclient like PostMan it returns data.

**Questions**

1) CORS restricts only ajax requests and not the normal HTTP requests because I believe postman sends normal http requests.

2) How does EnableCors restrict to provided origins? Consider if I modify the `origin and referrer` params in the ajax request I can fish the values. What strategy does CORS use to identify the referrer URL.

As W3C states HttpReferrer can be easily modified, one should not depend on its value to authorize the access. If that is the case What does EnableCors checking in behind to authorize the origin.

I could just change my origin in ajax request also. Please help me with this Iam pretty much confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> CORS restricts only ajax requests and not the normal HTTP requests because I believe postman sends normal http requests.

Yes, specifically *browsers* restrict Ajax requests — that is, browsers by default don’t allow frontend JavaScript code to access responses from cross-origin requests made with XMLHttpRequest, the Fetch API, or with Ajax methods from JavaScript libraries.

*Servers* don’t themselves enforce any restrictions on cross-origin requests; instead, servers send responses to any clients that make requests to them, including postman — and including browsers.

Browsers themselves always get the responses that any other client would; but just because the browser gets a response doesn’t mean the browser will allow frontend JavaScript code to access that response. Browsers will only expose a response for a cross-origin request to frontend code if the response includes the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

> How does EnableCors restrict to provided origins?

It doesn’t. When you CORS-enable a server, the only effect that has is to cause the server to send additional response headers, based on the values of particular request headers it receives — in particular, the `Origin` request header.

> Consider if I modify the `origin and referrer` params in the ajax request I can fish the values. What strategy does CORS use to identify the referrer URL.

Servers don’t (and can’t) do any validation of the `Origin` value to confirm it hasn’t been spoofed or whatever. But the CORS protocol doesn’t require servers to do that — because all CORS enforcement is done by browsers.

> As W3C states HttpReferrer can be easily modified, one should not depend on its value to authorize the access. If that is the case What does EnableCors checking in behind to authorize the origin.
>
> I could just change my origin in ajax request also. Please help me with this Iam pretty much confused

Browsers *know* the real origin of any frontend code that sends a cross-origin request, and browsers do CORS checks against what they know to be the real origin of the request — and not against the value of the `Origin` header.

Browsers are what *set* the `Origin` request header and send it over the network to begin with; they set the `Origin` value based on what they know to be the real origin, and not for their own use — because they already know what the origin is and that value is what they use internally.

So even if you manage to change an `Origin` header for a request, that won’t matter to the browser — it’s going to ignore that value and continue checking against the real origin.

*cf.* the answer at
*[In the respective of security, is it meaningful to allow CORS for specific domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40835863/in-the-respective-of-security-is-it-meaningful-to-allow-cors-for-specific-domai/40836602#40836602)*