# check if urls have the same origin

Tags: javascript

I have a function that runs before every API request to check if the request is from a valid origin.

I have an array of valid origins

```
const whitelist = [ 'a.com', 'b.co.uk' ]

const validOrigin = str => {
    const url = new URL( str )
    return whitelist.includes( url.host )
}

console.log(validOrigin('https://www.a.com'))
```

It returns false because of the `www.` I dont want to just add a copy with www. to the array of valid origins. I would like a way that covers this and everything else thats unexpected.

Comment: Tangential, but [it's well-known that the Origin header can be spoofed quite trivially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058183/whats-to-stop-malicious-code-from-spoofing-the-origin-header-to-exploit-cors) and it (and CORS, more broadly) is not intended to provide any security in this realm, nor should it be relied upon to make security-related decisions at any layer in your stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping in mind that, [by the rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin), `www.example.com` and `example.com` **are different origins**:

If you want to match any origin on the same domain or a subdomain of the domains in the whitelist, then you need to:

- Strip off the scheme and port - which you are doing already
- Check for an exact match - which you are doing already
- Check for a match which ends in `.` followed by the string (to stop `third-party-hacker-a.com` matching)

So something like:

```
const validOrigin = str => {
    const url = new URL( str )
    const host = url.host;
    return whitelist.some( element => {
        if (element === host) return true;
        return element.endsWith(`.${host}`);
    } )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[The `Array.prototype.includes` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) only accepts the value to search for, and looks for an exact match.

You would need to use a function that accepts a callback to test the elements - for example, [the `Array.prototype.findIndex` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex).

As you mention in the comments, you'll also need to change the `whitelist` so that you can exclude domains whose name ends with one of your valid domains.

```js
const whitelist = [ /(^|\.)a\.com$/i, /(^|\.)b\.co\.uk$/i ];

const validOrigin = str => {
    const url = new URL(str);
    const index = whitelist.findIndex(el => el.test(url.host));
    return index !== -1;
};

document.querySelectorAll("#tests > li").forEach(li => {
  const str = li.dataset.value;
  const result = validOrigin(str);
  li.textContent = `${str} = ${result}`;
});
```

```html
<ul id="tests">
  <li data-value="http://a.com/foo"></li>
  <li data-value="http://www.a.com/foo"></li>
  <li data-value="http://dev.a.com/foo"></li>
  <li data-value="http://banana.com/foo"></li>
  <li data-value="http://a.com.b.ru/foo"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: wouldnt this allow anything that ends in a.com though? like banana.com

Comment: @Will Good point; I've updated my answer.

Answer (score -1):

you can try something like this

```
str = str.replace( new RegExp("((http)(s)?:\/\/)?(www.)?","gm"),"")
```

this will delete the first part of the url